# C# AutoMapper - Set default value in dest property if not exist in source

Tags: c#, automapper, guid

I have:

```
Class A
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

Class B
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map **from A to B**, since "A" **doesn't** have `RequestId` I want to set it to **Guid.NewGuid()**

I tried this code:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<A, B>().ForMember(m => m.RequestId, o => Guid.NewGuid());
            
            });
            _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

But I'm still getting **empty** Guid in RequestId.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That mapping should look like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<A, B>().ForMember(m => m.RequestId, o => o.MapFrom(s => Guid.NewGuid()));
        
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change mapping confugration:

```cs
cfg.CreateMapper<A,B>().ForMember(x => x.RequestId, o => o.NullSubstitute(Guid.NewGuid());
```